# Ragnarök, and how to stop it, even when it's destined to happen

Tags: apocalypse, super-powers

This is a really tought question, in the world I'm building there is a destined event.  It's called Ragnarök, Darkest Night, the Apocalypse and Amargadon. This event is destined to happen. This event will be a giant war, gods vs demons. Evil vs good. Blah blah blah. When it happens the entire world will burn and die except two people. It's impossible to stop this event from happening. It's impossible to win the war. It's destiny as you can call it. However you can change the detail, and it only happens one time. In this world some people have superpowers. Could you save the world or something with one or two of these powers combined? Or maybe trick faith?
here's a list of noticable powers.

1. A girl that can slow down time as long as she wants, however she is the only one that can do things as normal while time is slowed down. She can also freeze time.
2. There is a boy in coma named the dreamer. Everything he dreams reality. However he is not aware he is dreaming. If he dreams about a giant snake. The snake always would've existed. Killing him won't stop Ragnarök.  (sorry if this is to confusing)
3. A boy that can create really strong illusions.
4. Someone with powers that are simular to Aang's powers.(AVATAR)
5. Someone that could freeze an entire city with a snap of her fingers.
6. Someone that can make portals that could transport an entire city. (Like a portal gun)
   (it's based on Rägnarok, the norse version, gods, monsters and humans all wait for Rägnarok and they all fight even when there's no chance they will win it)

Comment: it looks like you are asking people to write your book for you. Could you focus this question to some smaller aspect?

Comment: There's a standard get out, it's destined to happen, but is it destined to happen here and is it destined to happen now

Comment: Apart from the illogicity of asking us to change something which you state is impossible to stop in your world.... who is Aang?

Comment: Mythologies of all kinds are full of destinies being worked around. Well-known example: in order to lift the curse which prevented the Achaean fleet for sailing to Troy, Agamemnon had to sacrifice his daughter Iphigenia. It was the only way. So he sacrificed her, unavoidably. She was placed on the altar and Agamemnon struck the fatal blow. Yet she didn't die, because the goddess Artemis replaced her *in extremis* with a deer, and with her divine powers transported her to Tauris, where she became a priestess, and where she would eventually be reunited with her matricidal brother Orestes...

Comment: so the boy and girl are spared from this destruction thing... don't forget to destroy all condom too or your world is really doomed! I'm just saying.

Comment: I remember that myth from the trojan war, In fact I build it around the concept of the original Rägnarok. However I think it would be posible to work around it. Maybe some time freezing stuff.

Comment: So, you have created an inescapable event and you want advice on how to escape it? What is the relevance of giving anyone superpowers? What you need is one guy who can negotiate really really well. Admittedly, that makes the inescapable event escapable, but that is what you are asking for anyway.

Comment: so a quick explanation of superpowers. People got superpowers to fight at Rägnarok, Even they can't win. It's like the original norse version. People in Valhalla train for Rägnarok even when it's sure they lose.

Comment: My problem is that the OP is using Norse mythology without crediting it. His question would be much shorter if he just referenced that.

Comment: What exactly is impossible to stop? If it's just the fact that you can't win the war, you can still be defeated in a war without complete annihilation, a war can even end in status quo. I think you should be a lot clearer on your rules

Comment: okay it could start on multiple ways. Almost endless ways. Here are a few examples: 8 swords merging with each other so they can tear the universe in parts (longs story) , Hecate's torch being stolen and burns the universe, Arthur setting the air on fire,  Jörmungandr waking up. Fenrir wolf escapes his prison, The point is there's so many ways it can start. Bad guys constantly try to trigger it. People constantly try to prevent it but it's only postponement.  When it starts everyone will fight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a very interesting plot element in David Drake and Eric Flint's series [*Belisarius*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belisarius_series).

Long story short, the good guys are fighting a vastly superior force, united by unbreakable oaths. Yet Belisarius manages to find a way to make the enemy force break apart:

> *"But I suggest, if you haven't already, that you investigate the nature of that oath. Oaths are specific, you know."*
>
> (Belisarius speaking to the traitor Narses in Eric Flint and David Drake's *Fortune's Stroke*.)

I suggest you do the same thing. Destinies are specific, you know.

For example, when Prometheus stole the fire from the gods and gave it to the people, Zeus swore an oath that the thief will spend eternity chained to a stone. The oath was entered onto the tablets of Fate, and could not be broken. Yet later, when Zeus relented and consented to forgive Prometheus, he found a way to circumvent the destiny: he had Hephaestus make a circlet of gold with a tiny stone and put it on the finger of Prometheus; this is how rings with colored stones appeared in the world, and this is how Prometheus could be at the same time free and chained to a stone.

So you say that the unavoidable destiny is that the gods will have to fight the demons during Ragnarök, and they cannot win. But:

- Does the prophecy say *who* those gods are? Maybe the *current* gods cannot win, but *other* gods can. After all, gods don't hold power forever; for example, Zeus and Hera and Demeter and Poseidon are the *third generation* of gods, and even they were eventually replaced.
- The world will burn and die, and this is unavoidable. Does it say that this has to happen *at once*? Maybe the world will indeed burn, just that it will happen over thousands of years, one little piece at the time. And all men die anyway, so a prophecy saying that "all men will die" is rather cheap.
- The gods cannot win the war and this is unavoidable. But does it say that they have to *lose* it? After all, the U.S.A. did not win the Korean war, but they didn't lose it either. Maybe the war can end in an indefinite truce, as in [*Nochnoy Dozor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_Watch_(2004_film)).
- Even if the unavoidable fate is that the gods will lose the war, does the prophecy say what this *means*? For example, the U.S.A. lost the war in Vietnam, but nothing much happened as a result; Germany lost the world war, but after that it became one of the leading economic powers on Earth.
- Does the prophecy describe the *effects* of Ragnarök, and does it say they are *forever*? For example, Hercules was fatally poisoned by Nessus's blood-stained tunic, and he died and was cremated on the funeral pyre he himself built. But his immortal soul was raised to Olympus and became a god.

P.S. [Armageddon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armageddon) is a *place* (in northern Palestine), not an event. The prophecy is that during the end days, a great war will again be fought at Armageddon. (There was a [major battle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Megiddo_(15th_century_BC)) there between the Egyptians and the king of Kadesh in the 15th century BCE; the Egyptians won. There was another [major battle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Megiddo_(609_BC)) in the 7th century BCE between the Egyptians again and the Babylonians; the Egyptians won this one too.)

Comment: Upvote because I had never read about Prometheus' ring.  Also the other stuff is good.